# Rewrite list of maps to list of string in go-template

Tags: go, kubectl, go-templates

I have a following command:

```
kubectl get deployment my_dep -o go-template --template "{{( index .spec.template.spec.containers 0).env}}"
```

It returns:

```
[map[name:B value:VB]  map[name:A value:VA] map[name:C value:VC]...]
```

We can assume that each map on list has exactly one entry.
Is it possible to write such template that it rewrite it to following form:
`[B=VB, A=VA, C=VC,...]` ?

Comment: More index use: for the each level down one.

Comment: What do you mean? I have no guarantee that `C` is third on this list.

Comment: Then you cannot do it. It is that simple. There _is_ no builtin "search" function Go's templating engine.

Comment: @Volker I edited my question. Could you look again, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to write such template that it rewrite it to following form: [B=VB, A=VA, C=VC,...] ?

No.

None of the builtin functions allows to do this.